# UWP Item Navigation

Tags: c#, uwp, scroll, win-universal-app, desktop-application

I'd like to achieve this kind of behavior and layout which control is best suited to do this on UWP. The next button should go scrolling forward and the back button goes to the previous item(content)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear how it is implemented in this app. But we could use the [Frame.Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate?view=winrt-19041) method to achieve similar effects. Please refer to the following steps to do this.

1. Create three pages.(Right click project=> Add=>New Item=> Blank Page)
2. Add some controls to newly created page.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
..>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
 
        </Frame>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="NextText" Text="Next" Foreground="BlueViolet" PointerPressed="NextText_PointerPressed" Margin="0,0,100,0" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Fill="Blue" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse2" Fill="LightGray" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,10,0"  />
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse3" Fill="LightGray" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="BackText" Text="Back" PointerPressed="BackText_PointerPressed"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public SolidColorBrush Brush1;
    public SolidColorBrush Brush2;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Brush1=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        Brush2 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
        ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
    }

    private void NextText_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ellipse1.Fill = Brush2;
        ellipse2.Fill = Brush2;
        ellipse3.Fill = Brush2;
       

        var content=ContentFrame.Content;
        if (content != null)
        {
            var page = ContentFrame.Content.GetType();
            switch (page.Name)
            {
                case "BlankPage1": 
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));
                    ellipse2.Fill = Brush1; 
                    break;
                case "BlankPage2": 
                    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage3));
                    ellipse3.Fill = Brush1;
                    break;
                case "BlankPage3": 
                    break;
            }
        }          
            
    }

    private void BackText_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ellipse1.Fill = Brush2;
        ellipse2.Fill = Brush2;
        ellipse3.Fill = Brush2;
      
        if (ContentFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            ContentFrame.GoBack();             
        }

        var content = ContentFrame.Content;
        if (content != null)
        {
            var page = ContentFrame.Content.GetType();
            switch (page.Name)
            {
                case "BlankPage1":
                    ellipse1.Fill = Brush1;
                    break;
                case "BlankPage2":
                    ellipse2.Fill = Brush1;
                    break;
                case "BlankPage3":
                    ellipse3.Fill = Brush1;
                    break;
            }
        }
       
    }
}
```

BlankPage1.xaml:

```
<Page
  ..>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Page1"/>
        </StackPanel>    
</Grid>
</Page>
```

BlankPage2.xaml:

```
<Page
    ..>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Page2"/>
        </StackPanel>  
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Thank you, and how would you achieve the dots on the background that serve to indicate the page position you are in?

Comment: You could place [Ellipse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes#ellipse) outside the frame to do this and let multiple ellipses lay out horizontally. When you navigate to another page, you could check what page you located, then change Fill property of specified ellipse. I have updated the above code, please try it.